# ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password); eager laoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin, eager-loading

I'm trying to eager loading an associated entity (User and UserProfile) after this line of code in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method of my class OAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider:

```
ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
```

Today is working in this way:

```
await userManager.Users.Include("UserProfile").SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == context.UserName);
ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
```

I'm using eager loading before verifying the user, but I want load after user's verification. How can I do that?

Comment: I can't make these things line up - you want to wait until *after* something has happened to then "eager" load something? Wouldn't that just be loading?

Comment: The 'userManager.FindAsync' doesn't bring the associated object from 'UserProfile' type. I need to load it because I have to verify a property present in the 'UserProfile'. So, I load the object before use 'FindAsync', but I want to load direct to 'user.Userprofile' or something like that. I don't know how to do it.